# Make 2 cURL requets with $_POST

Tags: php, forms, post, curl

I am trying to do 2 requets in cURL. The first request is login me in, and I conserve a txt file to make the second requests when still loged.

The first part work like a charm, the second part doesn't work.

There is my code.

```
$lien = 'https://mysite.com/login';
$postfields = array(
    'username' => 'test',
    'password' => 'test'
);


$path_cookie = 'connexion.txt';
if (!file_exists(realpath($path_cookie))) touch($path_cookie);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $lien);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($path_cookie));

$return = curl_exec($curl);

echo($return);
curl_close($curl);


$lien2 = 'https://mysite.com/myform';
$postfields2 = array(
    'data1'     => 'test123',
    'data2'     => 'Account',
    'sort'      => '3',
    'fileFormat'    => '0',
    'timezone'  => 'Eastern+Standard+Time',
    'zeroRated' => 'true',
    'startDate'     => '2013-05-01',
    'endDate'   => '2013-05-31'
);

$curl = curl_init();


curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $lien2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath($path_cookie));

$return = curl_exec($curl); 

echo $return;
curl_close($curl);

unlink(realpath($path_cookie));
```

I am using the second part to $_post data to execute a form. The form processing takes place in the same page...

My connexion still on, but I don't know, the server is shooting me an error like :

> An exception occurred while processing your request. We recorded the exception..

It doesn't help me. Any one have an idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you take a look at apache's logs, maybe it will give some more informations

Comment: You may need to ask the developers of the service you are calling WHAT exception occured. Most likely the POST parameters are invalid or something.

Comment: Ask whoever is providing the error message what the exception is.

Comment: I'm trying to send the SAME parameters that the form is posting. I change the type of the form to Post --> Get, i execute the form, take all the url and take all those parameters. And I verify those, with the devtool of googlechrome looking in the form see if all the parameters i have are the same name/id of the fields of the form ... :S

Comment: Try testing your requests using http://www.hurl.it/

Comment: I don't have access to the provider, they don't give any support at all...

Comment: Matt Harrison, it's a good idea but I can't cause i need to be log first, and with hurl.it I can't do 2 requets at the same time ..

Comment: Thanks Jaay for the idea, but I just looked in the error_log file and There is nothing related to my problem, nothing for today at all..

Comment: You either can contact the service, or it's not a service you should be using. My guess is you're firing off two requests extremely rapidly, and their service just goes "no. rate limited". But, to find out, either read their documentation on requests, or contact them (or stop using them because they're clearly not a free, public service if neither of those apply).

Comment: Thanks Mike for the advice, I will write an email and try to get more informations about this error. Your suposition about the speed is maybe true, can I create a "timeout" between the 2 requests? I just tryed sleep(10) but it seem's to stop all the file before execute him, and not make a "timeout" between the 2 requests ...

Answer (score 0):

You have maybe a problem with SSL at this point.
Try to add these options:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

Comment: you can try to use my curl class, which i created for automatizations. i've putted a usage example with your attempt at the buttom. don't forget to define the constants at the top.
http://pastebin.com/P00xQbxZ

Answer (score 0):

finally I receive an answer from the support team. The "Eastern+Standard+Time" should be "Eastern Standard Time", the server will automaticly escape those string ... Thaks to every body for your help !